# Matching SQL Server table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

The thing I want to do is match the two table data.

I want to do with a stored procedure or trigger.

Version: SQL Server 2012

Source

```
Product        Reference
Type:int       Type:int    
-------------------------
  1 ------------  1    
  1 ------------  2    
  1 ------------  3    
  2 ------------  1    
  2 ------------  2    
  3 ------------  1    
  3 ------------  2    
  4 ------------  1    
  5 ------------  1    
  6 ------------  1
```

Result

```
Product        Reference
Type:int       Type:int
------------------------    
  1------------1    
  1------------2    
  1------------3    
  2------------1    
  2------------2    
  2------------3    
  3------------1    
  3------------2    
  3------------3    
  4------------1    
  4------------2    
  4------------3    
  5------------1    
  5------------2    
  5------------3    
  6------------1    
  6------------2    
  6------------3
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more info, please see How to Ask and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
create table Source ([ProductType] Int, ReferenceType Int)
insert into Source values
 ( 1 ,  1),
 ( 1 ,  2 ),
 ( 1 ,  3 ),
 ( 2 ,  1 ),
 ( 2 ,  2 ),
 ( 3 ,  1 ),
 ( 3 ,  2 ),
 ( 4 ,  1 ), 
  (5 ,  1 ),   
 ( 6 ,  1 )

 select distinct * from (select ProductType from Source) a
 cross join (select ReferenceType from Source) as b
```

You can see the live demo for output [here](https://rextester.com/NFJCK71831).

Comment: thank you so much.
this query solved my problem.
You're my best.

Comment: @cemalal You are welcome.

Comment: I'm a novice. I'm thinking of running this code as sql trigger. Partly the situation will be corrected. Can you fix this code for me. Permanent link: https://rextester.com/CVS3912

Comment: @cemalal What is the issue with the query in given in the link?